# Rendering a QWebElement into a QWidget crashes my application

Tags: qt, qt4, qtwebkit

I'm trying to render a QWebElement into a QWidget but my app crashes, however if I render it into an QImage everything works great.

Here is my code:

```
// using this code my application is crashing
void ImageWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    if (this->imgElement != NULL)
    {
        QPainter p(this);
        this->imgElement->render(&p);
        p.end();
    }
}

// using this one everything works OK
void ImageWidget::saveImage(QWebElement *el)
{
    this->imgElement = el;
    QImage m_image = QImage(290, 80, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    m_image.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter p(&m_image);
    el->render(&p);
    p.end();
    m_image.save("some_file.png", "png");
    this->update();
}
```

I'm using Qt 4.7.3 on Win 7 (x64). Let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: In the `QImage` example is `m_image` meant to be a member of `ImageWidget`?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend rendering webelemnt on paint event. Paint events can be fired to often or require to draw only tiny rect on widget.

Better to have image buffer and update it on web element change.

At least you can try to write "render ( painter, paintEvent->rect() );"